# Undefined reference error when using mexcuda ubuntu

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex

Ive installed matlab,gcc and CUDA toolkit on ubuntu .to use mexcuda .

but when i compile i get the following errors and i cant find any references on them anywhere .

```
Error using mex
/tmp/mex_42185702054896_15548/testmem04.o: In function `mexFunction':
tmpxft_00003e3a_00000000-5_testmem04.compute_70.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x152): undefined reference
to `__cudaPushCallConfiguration'
/tmp/mex_42185702054896_15548/testmem04.o: In function `__device_stub__Z9MulKernelPhPi(unsigned
char*, int*)':
tmpxft_00003e3a_00000000-5_testmem04.compute_70.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x35e): undefined reference
to `__cudaPopCallConfiguration'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

please note that when i first installed matlab, cuda 10 (my current version) was not supported by it , ive encountered the same thing when i installed matlab on windows , and fixed it by commenting a line in file "nvcc_g++.xml" and it works . when i did this in ubuntu matlab,matlab now detects the nvcc compiler but i get the previous error .

i realize "undefined reference errors " are linker errors , what should i do here ? i tried linking to cuda library but it didnt work .

Comment: You may not be linking the libraries you need.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How can i know which libraries are necessary? , when i google it i get no informative result .

Comment: Well, either you have coded it, and you know what functions you are using, or the person who coded should have informed you about it. However, this may have to do with the cc=70. Which GPU are you have?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I wrote the code and it works fine on windows , but when i tried to replicate the environment on ubuntu i got these errors. and im using GTX 1060 6gb

Comment: Why are you trying to compile with the cc=70 flag? Try to remove that from the `nvcc` options, compile only for the compute capability of your system first.

Comment: @AnderBiguri i just tried it and it returns the same error but without "compute_70"

Comment: well, without `compute_70` but with the compute of your GPU, I assume (61)

Comment: @AnderBiguri nope just "testmem04.cudafe1.cpp" for both occurrences

Answer (score 1):

For `mexcuda`, it is crucial that you match the CUDA toolkit to the version shipping with your installation of MATLAB (and Parallel Computing Toolbox). This is because Parallel Computing Toolbox ships a selection of libraries from the CUDA toolkit, and expects to be able to link against them. If you use the wrong version of the CUDA toolkit, all sorts of things can go wrong.

To check the appropriate version of the CUDA toolkit, look at the CUDA `ToolkitVersion` Version showing in the output from `gpuDevice`.

(Note that it is only the *toolkit* version that needs to match with MATLAB & PCT - it's almost always fine to get the latest driver).

For more details, see my answer https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/432360-after-uninstalling-cuda-toolkit-still-matlab-responds-for-gpudevice over there on MATLAB Answers.